# ReactNative application runs fine in Xcode 7.0.1 but the same application making issues with Xcode 8.1?

Tags: xcode, react-native, salesforce

Implemented ReactNative application for iOS integrated with Salesforce in Xcode 7.0.1, it was working fine, now getting issues trying to run the same application in Xcode 8.1 at /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ file not found or invalid or not compatible. codesign failed with exit code 1.

Thanks in advance, please help me out on this if you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

*First*: Did you clean your project before relaunching it with a new version of XCode?

*Secondly*: I think this is just an error raised by some "cached data" from the previous XCode. Delete the "build" folder from youApp/ios/ 
If it still doesn't work, you can edit your project settings by going to *File > Project Settings > Advanced * and setting product & Intermediates path. 
[image]